# Use of `is` and `as` in multiple conditions

Tags: c#

Quite recently, I thought about the use of `as`, `is` and direct cast in C#.

Logically, is it a better idea to use :

```
 var castedValue = value as type;
 if (null != castedValue)
 {
     // Use castedValue.
 }
```

than :

```
if (value is type)
{
    var castedValue = (type)value;
    // Use castedValue.
}
```

But I still have issues when dealing with this kind of pattern:

```
if (value is Implementation1)
{
    var castedValue = (Implementation1)value;
    // Use castedValue in a first way.
}
else if (value is Implementation2)
{
    var castedValue = (Implementation2)value;
    // Use castedValue in a second way.
}
else if (value is Implementation3)
{
    var castedValue = (Implementation3)value;
    // Use castedValue in a thrid way.
}
// And so on...
```

How can I improve this code to prevent casting two times when OK, and is it really necessary to cast twice?

I don't want to make the code unreadable, but the idea is not to test a cast if a previous one succeeded.

I had several ideas to fix this, but none of them seems to really satisfy the conditions...

**Edit:**

Here is a case I've got... There is this object that is created by a lower part of teh code I do not have control on. This object can be of several inherited types. In my layer, I do want to create a specific object depending on this type. I do have this constructor class:

```
public static IHighLevelObject MakeHighLevelObject(LowLevelObject lowLevelObject)
{
    IHighLevelObject highLevelObject;

    if (lowLevelObject is LowLevelObject1)
    {
        highLevelObject = new HighLevelObject1((LowLevelObject1)lowLevelObject);
    }
    else if (lowLevelObject is LowLevelObject2)
    {
        highLevelObject = new HighLevelObject2((LowLevelObject2)lowLevelObject);
    }
    else if (lowLevelObject is LowLevelObject3)
    {
        highLevelObject = new HighLevelObject3((LowLevelObject3)lowLevelObject);
    }
    // And so on...

    return highLevelObject;
}
```

How do I solve this case ?

Comment: What is your problem with the code above? If it's stylistic, I'm afraid there isn't much you can do about it. If you're worried about the possible correctness/performance implications of casting multiple times, remember that the `is` operator doesn't perform a cast, but is rather a low-level MSIL instruction that is optimized and efficient.

Comment: My question was indeed a performance issue question. If `is` is optimized and efficient, maybe my first assumption about using `as` instead of `is` + cast is not so true, or does not make a real difference...

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here for a related discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2139818/701054

Comment: That is precisely the kind of discuss that made me think about the given problem: `as` would get better performance here, but `is` is much more convinient to use...

Comment: What will happen if a new `LowLevelObjectN` class will be created that previously didn't exist?

Comment: @almaz you're right on this, we'd have to modify this class...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This kind of code suggests design issues that you need to tackle first.

The code breaks [Open-Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): whenever you need to add a new implementation type to extend the functionality you'll have to edit this class. You should design your solution so that logic branching is done via generalized approach, e.g. using polymorphism. Since you have provided a very general description it is hard to suggest appropriate solution for your problem.

Comment: True, and might solve the problem in a given case, but not always and there is no attempt to actually answer the question here.

Comment: @pdr Question: How can I improve this code to prevent casting two times.  My answer suggests approach that will prevent both casts.

Comment: +1 for seeing through the question and identifying the actual issue.

Comment: @almaz: That's not the question at all. The question is: what is the best approach to safe and direct casting, where the number of conditions is greater than one. I can think of a case I have where that question could be asked and your answer offers nothing. Cause I already thought of that. I think Avner's comment should be an answer and your answer a comment.

Comment: @pdr I've added the answer while question was still in CodeReview. I reviewed the code and highlighted the root issue.

Comment: almaz, thanks for your answer. I think your point is quite good in the interface implementation case. Still, the problem may arise with inheritance and classes extending functionnalities. In this case, I am not sure this sort of blocks can really be avoided. But I might be wrong and need to think wider.

Comment: @clemchen - Yes, you need to. You just need an abstract/virtual function on the base class, and the correct implementation on each subclass.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming polymorphism is nowhere on the radar, you can use multiple `return`s and use `as`.

```
public static IHighLevelObject MakeHighLevelObject(LowLevelObject lowLevelObject)
{
    LowLevelObject1 object1 = lowLevelObject as LowLevelObject1;
    if (object1 != null)
    {
        return new HighLevelObject1(object1);
    }
    LowLevelObject2 object2 = lowLevelObject as LowLevelObject2;
    if (object2 != null)
    {
        return new HighLevelObject2(object2);
    }
    // And so on...
}
```

Your `LowLevelObject` class could just have a virtual `ToHighLevelObject` method that each subclass overwrites and avoid this nastiness to begin with.

Comment: +1, thanks, I'll mark almaz as answer for the general case. For the particular case, this indeed works, I didn't see this simple solution for my wanting to have one return place, but here this seems better.